# RD Mailform with PHP Mailer Version 5.2.9 not more working

Tags: php, phpmailer, mail-form

I'm using PHP Mailer since 1 year, embedded in a Dreamweaver Template. Everything was working perfectly in 8 Websites with different contactforms. Yesterday I saw, in IE Edge after sending, it shows only MF004 on a white page. In Firefox its working some times.

Its different sites with different PHP-Versions, 5.6 / 7.1 /7.2 with all Versions the same error and some days before everything was perfect. We didn't change anything at these websites in the last 3 weeks. I have no more idea.

Comment: The only thing I think we can take from this is you're getting white screen. That should mean you have stuff in your error log you can take a look at, or if not, you should check your error reporting is set appropriately.

Comment: You need to show us the code that doesn't work. We have no idea what's going on in your code. A side note, the browser isn't called IE Edge. IE and Edge are two completely different browsers.

Comment: I also found [this repo](https://github.com/ZemezPlugins/rd-mailform) for RD Mailform, where, in the code, `MF004` seems to be an error code from the RD Mailform-code: `'MF004': 'Please, define type of your form!',`

Comment: You're also using a very old version of PHPMailer with many known bugs and vulnerabilities, so upgrade to the latest version (6.x).

Comment: thank you all for your time and answers. I tried the basic form I got with the template and it runs. For the actual form I created new fields by cpy and paste and found an error in the fieldtype range. So it was no php error. But you are right, its an old version. For the future I would like to update to version 6. can somebody tell me how can I do this ?
Im not a PHP specialist. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think now, the Problem is - I need the PHPmailer update to version 6.
So I saw, the structure of the files are different and now I don't know how I can update without composer. Where I must insert the "use" and "require" lines, in rd-mailform.php ? and whichone first etc.
Thank you